# Creating a folder from text file with indexing letters

Tags: batch-file

I have the batch script below. It should read the first character of every line of a text file. Is that is a to z, it should make a subfolder in the corresponding folder. It is somethins else, it should be created in the "_other" folder.

So if i have a list:

```
123test
aaatest
bbbtest
```

It should create:

```
c:\dirs\_other\123test
c:\dirs\a\aaatest
c:\dirs\b\bbbtest
```

But for some reason my last if/else does not work. Why not? this is the script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=c:\klantenlijst.txt
FOR /F "delims=~" %%i IN (!file!) DO (
set var=%%i 
set str=!var:~0,1!
IF !str!==A ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==B ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==C ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==D ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==E ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==F ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==G ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==H ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==I ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==J ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==K ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==L ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==M ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==N ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==O ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==P ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==Q ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==R ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==S ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==T ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==U ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==V ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==W ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==X ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==Y ( set letter=1 )
IF !str!==Z ( set letter=1 )

IF !letter!==1 ( md c:\Dirs\!str!\!var! ) ELSE ( md c:\Dirs\_Other\!var! )

)
```

Comment: post file klantenlijst.txt

Comment: It contains for testing just 4 records. All 0-9,a-z,A-Z and spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another quick way to verify whether a character is a letter.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=c:\klantenlijst.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i IN (%file%) do (
   set var=%%i
   set str=!var:~0,1!
   if /i "!str!" geq "A" if /i "!str!" leq "Z" set "str=_other"
   md "c:\dirs\!str!\!var!"
)
```

One difference with this approach is that non-English letters with diacriticals will also be counted as letters. These non-English letters all have extended ASCII codes greater than 127. This is the same result that Andriy's FINDSTR method gets.

Comment: When you said "the above approach", you meant @Aacini's, right? For I can't see how your suggestion's results would be different to mine's.

Comment: @AndriyM - By above, I meant the approach in my answer - a poor choice of words. I believe our approaches give the same result, yes.

Comment: Ah, I see, I believe my perception was slanted somehow, even though I myself often use the word "above" to refer to parts of text in my own posts. A double lesson for me. Perhaps you didn't need to change the wording because of me, but thank you very much for jumping to it!

Answer (score 5):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set letters=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
set file=c:\klantenlijst.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
   set var=%%i
   set str=!var:~0,1!
   for %%a in ("!str!") do if "!letters:%%~a=!" equ "%letters%" set str=_other
   md "c:\dirs\!str!\!var!"
)
```

The program above tries to delete the first character from a string comprised of all the letters; if the result is the same, then the first character is NOT a letter. This method is faster because it does not use any external .exe command.

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

In next examples below I write first a command and then its output.

The `letters` variable contain the 26 letters, that is:

```
echo !letters!
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Batch allows to replace part of a variable value this way:

```
echo !letters:M=123!
ABCDEFGHIJKL123NOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

If the replacement string is not given, the original substring is just deleted:

```
echo !letters:M=!
ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

If the original substring is contained in *another variable*, the replacement is achieved with its value. For example, if the variable have a letter:

```
set str=M
echo !letters:%str%=!
ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

On the other hand, if the variable have NOT a letter, the new value remains the same as the original:

```
set str=1
echo !letters:%str%=!
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

This way, if you compare `"!letters:%str%=!"` versus `"%letters%"`; if the result is DIFFERENT, then str variable contain a letter; otherwise str variable contain a non-alphabetic character.

However, you must note that str variable is modified *inside* a FOR loop. This means that its value must be replaced using DelayedExpansion, but this result in the following funny code: `"!letters:!str!=!"` that, of course, is invalid. The way to fix this detail is changing `!str!` value by a FOR replaceable parameter and then use the parameter in the replace substring expression.

You must note that previous replacement is achieved by cmd.exe processor immediately as the normal processing of the Batch file. On the other hand, the execution of `ECHO !str! | FINDSTR /I "[A-Z]"` requires the loading of FINDSTR.EXE file (about 30 KB size) and the execution of *two* copies of CMD.EXE in order to execute each side of the pipeline, and this process is executed *for each name in the list!*. This mean that this method is *much slower* than the former one, and the timing difference will be evident if the list of names is large.

Comment: Did you mean 'The script above tries' ? I had a bit of trouble understanding it :)

Comment: No, I didn't understand 'Previous program try to delete ...', but nice explanation anyway...

Comment: "Previous program delete the first character from letters..." But if the first char is not a letter? Then it will not be deleted... So? "Previous program TRY to delete the first char from letters". Is this confusing? How do you said that?

Comment: No I didn't understand 'Previous program', I thought you meant the program in the previous answer, then I was trying to figure out how the previous answer matched what you were saying...

Comment: +1, What about `if /i "!letters:%%~a=!" equ "%letters%"` ? For lower case.

Comment: @Endoro: For lower case: `echo "!letters:m=!"`=`"ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`; `if "ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" equ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. The `if` compare `"%letters%"` versus itself without one letter, so the `/i` option is not needed even if the deleted letter is lower case.

Comment: @Endoro: String replacement is unconditionally case-insensitive (at least as long as the system is case-insensitive, I guess), if that's what you were asking about.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FINDSTR` to test if the first character is a letter:

```
...
ECHO !str! | FINDSTR /I "[A-Z]" 1>NUL && (
  command to execute if !str! is a letter
) || (
  command to execute if !str! is not a letter
)
...
```

The `"[A-Z]"` pattern matches any letter and the `/I` switch makes the matching case-insensitive.

For instance, you could set `str` to `_other` if it is not a letter. That way you would not need any more conditions when using the value as the name of the folder in which the subfolder should be created:

```
...
ECHO !str! | FINDSTR /I "[A-Z]" 1>NUL || (
  SET str=_other
)
MD "c:\Dirs\!str!\!var!"
...
```

Please note also the double quotes around the path in `MD`. That is necessary when the path contains spaces or other special characters. (Thanks @Peter Wright for the note.)

Comment: Oh, very good! Nevertheless, in the original code, there were two further bugs beyond the `/i` requirement that Endoro pointed out. The first was that `letter` was being assigned a value of `"1 "` not `"1"` because the space is included in a string `set`. You could have cured this either by eliminating the space after the `1` or by using a `set /a` instead. The second was that once `letter` had been set, it would never be UNset, so any NON-letter intial character that appeared after the first LETTER initial character would have ALSO been classed as a letter...

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I added /i for ignoring the case of the letters, and deleted the space so that letter=1. Last problem is that the lines in the script contain spaces and this causes problems. How to solve this? Do I need to add quotes?

Comment: Quoting the directorynames to be created like this `IF !letter!==1 ( md "c:\Dirs\!str!\!var!") ELSE ( md "c:\Dirs\_Other\!var!")` should cure your spaces problem, if I've understood it correctly.

Comment: You need to add the `/B` option, or else start your search string with `^` to make sure that you match only the first character of the line.\

Comment: @dbenham: The `str` is assigned a single character (the `var`'s first one), so, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Good point about the quotes, @Peter, thanks, I somehow forgot to add that. Adding it now.

Comment: Ach, I see it now. I was thinking `!str!` referred to the entire string.

Comment: FYI - The FINDSTR regex range `[A-Z]` includes non-English letters with diacriticals.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for `a`, only for `A`:

```
IF !str!==A ( set letter=1 )
```

replace it with:

```
IF /i !str!==A ( set letter=1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I added /i for ignoring the case of the letters, and deleted the space so that letter=1. Last problem is that the lines in the script contain spaces and this causes problems. How to solve this? Do I need to add quotes?

Comment: best is: `IF /i "!str!"=="A" set /a letter=1`